# Cassandra Data Model for apache access logs

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

In a POC, we are using cassandra for storing (among other things) Apache access logs (parsed) and use together with apache spark + zeppelin. We have managed to get things working BUT we are very uncertain about how to model the data correctly.

**Edit:** Our queries will span over months and years rather than weeks and days. Against production jobs are likely executed perhaps daily (at least for now) and we will use a smaller dataset during development.

Since this will be used for analytics ONLY, the queries can be pretty much anything but of course we could consider a handful of queries in advance.

I.e

- latency percentiles
- geo distribution
- sum of requests
- Popular rest resources
- ... etc

Partition key + Primary key. This is really difficult... the only thing that I can think of is something like *((userid, [webresource]), timestamp)*.
At least this would give a fairly even distribution. Otherwise we would have to use a checksum or something which feels wrong.

Or should I have different tables for different types, like latency, geo etc? Or is this a good option for materialized views?

I have googled for something like this without any luck so perhaps cassandra is a poor solution for this BUT still, we would really like to see how far we can get.

Anyway, any input is highly appreciated!

Regards /Johan

Comment: Please provide more specific details - how queries should look like (for example do you want perform query for last day/week/overall?), how often you'll execute them, etc.

Comment: Thanks @alex, I have updated the question with this info,